# What is Code Sense in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I am new to Xcode and have following query:
What is Code Sense in Xcode and how do I enable/disable in it in Xcode 4.5?

Please correct me if I am wrong, but are the M and A boxes shown in project navigator related to code sense.

Comment: code sense is also known as auto completion. That's the important function that turns NSStr into NSStream and UIViewCo into UIViewContentmode. Because we all know those are the most important things in the world ;-)

Comment: oh. Is it that simple a thing! thanks @MatthiasBauch . Can you also answer the above change I made in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M and A are not for code sense, these are the status of your file as XCode also maintain a local GIT repository for your project. M is for Modified and A is for Added.

You can create a local GIT repo with XCode when you create your project -

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you also mention how its enabled in Xcode. Its not being displayed in my system but I've seen it in other's Xcode.